# Kentico CMS Repeater UniPager shows everything on one page

Tags: asp.net, kentico, ascx, asprepeater, kentico-12

I have the following code in front:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="RepItems" runat="server" DataBindByDefault="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        //code
    </ItemTemplate>
</cms:CMSRepeater>
<div class="paging-bar flex">
    <cms:UniPager ID="Pager" runat="server">
        <PageNumbersTemplate>
            //template code here
        </PageNumbersTemplate>
    </cms:UniPager>
</div>
```

And in the code behind I call this method in `SetupControl()`

```
var data = //call to webservice
if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(data))
{
    RepItems.DelayedLoading = true;
    RepItems.DataSource = data;
    DataBind();
    RepItems.ControlContext = ControlContext; //tried with and without
    RepItems.EnablePaging = true; //tried with and without
    RepItems.PageSize = PagingPageSize; //tried with and without
    RepItems.UniPagerControl = Pager; //tried with and without


    Pager.PageSize = PagingPageSize;
    Pager.DisplayFirstLastAutomatically = true;
    Pager.DisplayPreviousNextAutomatically = true;
    Pager.HidePagerForSinglePage = true;
    Pager.GroupSize = 3;
    Pager.PageControl = RepItems.ID;
    Pager.UseQueryParameterForFirstPage = true;
    Pager.PagerMode = CMS.DocumentEngine.Web.UI.UniPagerMode.Querystring;

    //DataBind();
}
```

But the repeater shows all the items with no paging. Is there something I'm missing? When debugging I get the expected values for PagingPageSize but Repeater.PageCount always gives me a value of 1.

I've followed everything according to the K12 docs https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/developing-websites/kentico-controls/generic-controls/paging-controls/unipager

Answer (score 0):

Try the BasicRepeater control instead of the CMSRepeater.

- BasicRepeater should be used exactly in these situations when you set the data source of the repeater manually.
- CMSRepeater should be used when you try to display pages that are loaded by the CMSRepater automatically via the "Path" property.

Comment: I tried that and moved the DataBind() method to OnPreRender() but the paging still isn't applied